# How to store hex colors in an array

Tags: java, arrays

How do I store hex colors like in the following table in a private array?

```
Name    R   G   B
BLACK   00  00  00
NAVY    00  00  80
BLUE    00  00  FF
```

The names of the colors are stored in a public enum. the array also should be the class attribute.

```
public enum COLOR_NAMES {
    BLACK, NAVY, BLUE
}
```

Comment: "the array also should be the class attribute" - what does that mean?

Comment: You create a class with 4 fields (`COLOR_NAMES name`, `int r`, `int g`, `int b`), then create an array of that.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the enum to store the values for you:

```
public enum COLORS {
    BLACK(0x00, 0x00, 0x00),
    NAVY(0x00, 0x00, 0x80),
    BLUE(0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);

    private int red;
    private int green;
    private int blue;

    private COLORS(int red, int green, int blue) {
        this.red = red;
        this.green = green;
        this.blue = blue;
    }

    public int getRed() {
        return this.red;
    }

    public int getGreen() {
        return this.green;
    }

    public int getBlue() {
        return this.blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: the enum and the array should be seperated (enum public, array private access)

Comment: The problem is, you cannot use a enum as array-key in java. You could use a map I guess, but why do the colorvalues need to be private?

Comment: it´s an assignment